# Use secrets with Azure function binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-eventhub

I'm using Azure Event Hubs output binding for Azure Functions.

```
[EventHub("dest", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]IAsyncCollector<string> outputEvents,
```

How can I use the local.setting.json file to pass the secret using key Vault?

I don't want to write my connection string in the local.setting.json file, but I do need to bind it to the Connection param.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After creating Azure key vault you need to run the below command to add the secrets to the vault

```
az keyvault create -n mySuperSecretVault -g jeffhollan-keyvault -l westus

az keyvault secret set --vault-name mySuperSecretVault -n eventHubConnectionString --value '{MyEventHubConnectionString}'

az keyvault secret set --vault-name mySuperSecretVault -n superSecret --value 'I love Azure Functions'
```

After creating Azure Function, you need to enable the managed service identity for the function app. That will help in adding identity in my Azure active directory.

In the Azure Portal (or via Visual Studio / VS Code / CLI / whatever tool you want to use to manage app settings), I need to associate some app settings to correspond to the secrets in key vault. To do that I will create two new application settings for `SuperSecret` and `EventHubConnectionString` that mirror the `local.settings.json` — but instead of having the secrets in the app settings, I will point to where the secrets are in my key vault. It should be noted that the key vault secret ID is itself not a secret, it’s just an address of where the secret can be found.

Check the [Getting Key Vault Secrets in Azure Functions](https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b) .